# Floating point calculation

Tags: numbers, floating-point

Apologies for an ambiguous title. My problem is this: Given a vector of doubles `w` with entries less than one, a second vector of doubles `v` with positive entries that sum to less than one (computed with the recursion below), and a double `u` which is positive and less than one, extend `v` using the recursion

```
w(i) = RandomNumber(); //A random number from (0,1) - not necessarily uniform
v(i) = v(i-1)*w(i)*(1-w(i-1))/w(i-1);
```

until `sum(v)>1-u`. The problem is that `u` might be quite small, and since the `v(i)`'s are (stochastically) decreasing they can get tiny too. And we might get `w(i)` close to one as well.

What's the safest way to implement this? Points for accuracy :)

Answer (score 0):

One common way to sum floating point numbers without too much error is to sum them from smallest to largest. Since your calculation of `v(i)` only depends on `v(i-1)`, you can keep the past numbers in a sorted tree, with recursive sums kept at each node, and the immediately preceding value in a separate variable. When you insert a new value, or rearrange some node, you then need to recalculate the sums going up the tree from those points. The summation at each node could be straight up addition, or something that preserves a few more bits like Kahan summation.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe instead of accumulating v(i)'s and comparing it to 1-u, you start with 1-u, and decrease each v(i) until you get to a negative number? The accuracy is better the closer you are to 0.

Comment: Yes, maybe this would give an OK approximation for small u's (is that what you mean by accuracy is better -> 0?). I'd have to think about it a little more.

Comment: The distance between two successive floating point values (either float or double) depends on the values. The closer you are to 0 - the smaller this distance is (this is due to the internal representation). See http://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/ for a list of some blog posts which might be useful.

Comment: Misread you the first time - thought you were implying that the final sum would be 1-u, which isn't quite right obviously, but I see now what you meant. Thanks

Comment: This has the potential to fall over badly. If your `v` values decrease too quickly, then you can get to a point where subtracting it from the remaining part of `1-u` gives exactly the same number that you had at the previous step. Then you can get stuck running forever. You really will need to keep a sum of your series, and test directly against that at each step.

Comment: @Novelocrat - Why is this any different then adding? If subtracting will not change the number, then adding will not change the number (at least in most cases). You can easily overcome this by comparing the current value with the one from the previous step. But these are details. According to the question, v(i) is (mostly) decreasing so it is better to be closer to 0 when i is larger.

Comment: You can control how you sum the `v(i)` in order to not lose low-order bits. One could include `-(1-u)` in that summation, and gain a little bit of accuracy in the final comparison, but the point is that one should not be forced to do operations between `1-u` and the `v` values prematurely, lest they underflow.

Comment: Ah, I see your point now. Thanks. I was putting too much weight on the fact that v(i)'s are decreasing, without considering that the first ones might also be too small.

Comment: It's not just the first ones, it's that adding/subtracting the next number against the running total could underflow at any point in the series, and everything after that point would also underflow and be lost, even if in aggregate they would add up.